# Vary function overload based on generic type

Tags: typescript, overloading

How can I provide a function overload that is based on one of the arguments having the `never` type?

```
type Message<T> = { id: string };

function publish<T>(message: Message<T>, payload: T) {
  // ...
}
```

If the `T` is `never` that implies that the message never has a payload and therefore I don't want the function to expect a `data` argument.

I overloaded the function to provide an alternate signature for the `never` case, which makes the `payload` argument optional.

```
function publish(message: Message<never>, payload?: never): void

function publish<T>(message: Message<T>, payload: T): void {
  // ...
}
```

This works in the `Message<never>` case, but it breaks all other calls:

```
let NeverMessage: Message<never> = { id: "never-message" };
let NumberMessage: Message<number> = { id: "number-message" };

publish(NeverMessage);
// All good!

publish(NumberMessage, 10);
// function publish(message: Message<never>, payload?: undefined): void
// Argument of type '10' is not assignable to parameter of type 'undefined'
```

How can I overload the definition without making making `payload` optional in both signatures?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAshDO8CGBzCAeAKgPigXigG8oBLAEwC4p5gAnEgOxSgF8BuAKA4DMBXBgMbASAewZQwvAEYAbEvAAWACgC2CZGipxEqDAwgA3CLWwAaCUhAyRSMgH4q+o7QCUVAyPJc+g4WInScopY2KrqulrhaCHmYJbWtlSYblAe5EQcUFAA9NlQAHSFHCxcMhDAUAByhsbaGhCROtFOxrgExORUAEQttAC0ak0QXaycZRWVvCpStVENsHPoDFMzJvhEpJRQPSvGA3Mj7FySsvLK1c51ui6cJ0Hnu7RXaOYAjAAMN0A)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not really [overloading](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) the function the way you think you are.  An overloaded function has an ordered list of *call signatures* which are visible to callers of the function and have no implementation (they end in a `;` and not a `{...}`), and a single *implementation signature* which is visible to the implementation of the function.  You ostensibly want callers and not just the implementation to see the `publish<T>(message: Message<T>, payload: T): void` signature.  If so, you need to do something like this:

```
// call signatures
function publish(message: Message<never>, payload?: never): void;
function publish<T>(message: Message<T>, payload: T): void;

// implementation signature
function publish<T>(message: Message<T>, payload: T): void {
  // ...
}
```

That should fix your problem as stated.

---

As an aside, note that it is [discouraged](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-is-astring-assignable-to-anumber-for-interface-at--) to have a generic type like

```
type Message<T> = { id: string };
```

where the type parameter is unused.  TypeScript's type system is primarily [structural](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-structural-typing) and not nominal, meaning that if two types have the same *structure*, then they are the same type, even if you use different names to refer to them.  In this case, `Message<never>` and `Message<number>` are both `{ id: string }`, and therefore they are the same type.

It is possible that the compiler will treat an expression explicitly typed as `Message<never>` differently from one explicitly typed as `Message<number>`, and that your overloads will turn out to behave the way you want.  But there is no guarantee that this will always work, and [weird stuff](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-doesnt-type-inference-work-on-this-interface-interface-foot---) can happen when it doesn't.

The conventional wisdom here is to use the type parameter somewhere in the structure of your type.  Even something like

```
type Message<T> = { id: string; __messageType?: T };
```

is sometimes enough to get things working, even though there need not be any `__messagetype` property at runtime.

And you might also need to be careful with subtypes and supertypes, as even the above `Message<T>` definition has `Message<never>` being a subtype of any `Message<T>`, meaning you can call `publish(NeverMessage, "hello there");` with no error.  The value `NeverMessage` will be perceived as a valid `Message<"hello there">`.  To prevent *that* you'll need to make `Message<T>` [invariant in `T`](https://www.stephanboyer.com/post/132/what-are-covariance-and-contravariance), which can be accomplished if you've got [`--strictFunctionTypes`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#strict-function-types) enabled by a function property like this:

```
type Message<T> = { id: string; __messageType?: (x: T) => T };
```

And you'd need to widen the implementation signature too:

```
function publish(message: Message<never>, payload?: never): void;
function publish<T>(message: Message<T>, payload: T): void;
function publish<T>(message: Message<T> | Message<never>, payload?: T): void {
  // ...
}
```

This would result in

```
publish(NeverMessage); // okay
publish(NumberMessage, 10); // okay
publish(NeverMessage, "hello there"); // error!
```

... uh, but I digress, as you weren't asking about this.

The answer to your main question is to remember to add a separate implementation signature.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAshDO8CGBzCAeAKgPigXigG8oBLAEwC4p5gAnEgOxQG4oB9NgWwWTU3AgB+KpigBfZgChJAMwCuDAMbASAewZQwcgEYAbEvAAWACm6JUEKnHNp0DCADcItbABpNSELtVIywqPZOtACUVA6q5FLySirqmjr6RljYpjwWVmm2OO5gnt6+IqFQ4ZGyCspqGlp6BobJqTaWsJkY2R5ePpRQmEUlZESSUFAA9MNQAHSTkmLSuhDAUAByjs7WvE1rFnYrLvhEpF0ARIHOALRm64fiUnMLi3Kc2qstGY12D0+7BMTkVMcfZwuFiuEmkkmqiRMyyCmzQwSkENqxnuj2ejXcAEYAAzw8EJJHQtHrdyHQwQXTeKDAMm0CCHXGSIA)